# java.time.LocalDateTime to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, java-time, localdatetime

I am trying to implement java.time to parse different date formats and return as java.sql.Date. However I am loosing time if I use java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate date).
How I can achive the same way as java.sql.Date(java.util.Date date.getTime())?
Possible formats in my application are.

DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ssZ");
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTimeFormatter datetimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
DateTimeFormatter datetimeFormatterMil = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

```
import java.sql.Date;
public Date oslcStringToDate(String str) throws ParseException
    {
        //remove colon in time zone
        Date date = null;
        if (!str.equalsIgnoreCase(NULL)) {
            int colonPos = str.length() - 3;
            str = str != null && str.length() > 3 && str.charAt(colonPos) == ':' ? 
                    str.substring(0, colonPos) + str.substring(colonPos + 1) 
                    : str.endsWith("Z") ? 
                        str.substring(0, str.length() - 1) + "+0000" 
                        : str;
            date = str.indexOf("T") > 0 ? 
                    str.indexOf(".") > 0 ? 
                        java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDateTime.parse(str, datetimeFormatterMil).toLocalDate())
                        : java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDateTime.parse(str, datetimeFormatter).toLocalDate())
                    : java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDateTime.parse(str, dateFormatter).toLocalDate());
        }
        return date;
    }
```

Comment: "*loosing time*"--> [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html) of `java.sql.Date`: "To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by **setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero** ..." (emphasis mine) || if `java.sql.Date(java.util.Date date.getTime())` works, you can convert the `LocalDateTime` to an `Instant` and use the `toEpochMilli()` method to use instead of `Date.getTime()` [but `java.sql.Date` is not expected to carry time]

Comment: Give an example of your input string being passed to the `oslcStringToDate` method.

Comment: Please explain the real problem you're trying to solve. The equivalency is `java.sql.Timestamp` <>`java.time.LocalDateTime` and `java.sql.Date` <> `java.time.LocalDate`. `java.sql.Date` is not supposed to have a time component (it just appears to have it because of the awkward inheritance from `java.util.Date`). And given JDBC supports the `java.time` types, you should have no need to continue to use the legacy types likes `java.sql.Date`.

Answer (score 2):

## Do not mix legacy and modern classes

> if I use java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate date)

Never mix the terrible legacy classes with their replacement, the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

When handed an object of a legacy class, immediately convert. You can convert to and fro by way of `to…`/`from…`/[`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf(java.time.LocalDate)) methods found on the old classes.

```
LocalDate ld = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate() ;
```

And the other direction.

```
java.sql.Date d = Date.valueOf( myLocalDate ) ;
```

## Avoid legacy classes

With [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) [4.2](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) and later, support for the *java.time* classes is required in your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver).

So use only the *java.time* classes. No need to ever use either `Date`, nor `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `Timestamp`, etc.

## Date-only values

The `LocalDate` class represents a date-only, without a time-of-day, without a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So a `LocalDate` is a year, month, and day — nothing more.

The `java.sql.Date` class *pretends* to represent a date-only value. But due to a tragically poor design decision, the class inherits from `java.util.Date` which *does* have a time-of-day. And even more confusing, the `java.util.Date` class is supposed to represent a moment as seen in UTC, but nevertheless contains a time zone used when generating text. These legacy classes are a [master class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_class) in how to *not* do [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

You said:

> However I am loosing time if I use java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate date).

If you mean the resulting `java.sql.Date` has no time-of-day, yes, of course, that is a feature, not a bug. As mentioned above, objects of this class actually *do* have a time-of-day because of inheritance, but the class pretends to have a date-only (year-month-day).

You said:

> How I can achive the same way as java.sql.Date(java.util.Date date.getTime())?

I cannot understand your goal here. So, after again advising against ever using these awful legacy classes, I will layout some of the possible types for use with SQL.

| standard SQL | java.time ☑️ | legacy ❌ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `DATE` | `LocalDate` | `java.sql.Date` |
| `TIME` | `LocalTime` | `java.sql.Time` |
| `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` | `LocalDateTIME` | *no support* |
| `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` | `OffsetDateTime` | `java.sql.Timestamp` |

## ISO 8601

Your Question is not clear, but apparently you are trying to parse text in the format of "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ".

This format happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2022-01-23T12:34:56.789Z" ) ;
```

To generate such text:

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

To record to a database, convert to the class mapped in JDBC to the standard SQL type of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

That SQL name is a misnomer, as the SQL standard was written with mere offset-from-UTC in mind, not [real time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the temporal prime meridian of UTC. A time zone, in contrast, is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Note that `LocalDateTime` is exactly the *wrong* class to be using in this context. The `LocalDateTime` class purposely lacks the context of an offset or zone. With only a date and a time-of-day, a `LocalDateTime` object is inherently ambiguous with regard to the timeline.

If you want to store only the date portion of your ISO 8601 string, you will need to think about time zones. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. A moment can be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US.

Call `toLocalDate` to extract the date portion of an `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
LocalDate dateInTokyo = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ).toLocalDate() ;
LocalDate dateInUtc = instant.atOffset ZoneOffset.UTC ).toLocalDate() ;    
LocalDate dateInToledo = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ).toLocalDate() ;  // Time zone name for Toledo Ohio US is `America/New_York`.
```

Write to a database column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `DATE`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , dateInTokyo ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

---

All of these issues have been covered many many times already in Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: The legacy equivalent for `TIME`/`java.time.LocalTime` is [`java.sql.Time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Time.html)